# write user input to a file

Tags: bash

I'm trying to get information saved to a file, but I'm only getting the last line.

Is my method for saving the output, `> $fqdn_alias.decom`, is wrong?

```
qdn_alias=$(hostname --alias)
blade_sn=$(dmidecode -t system | grep "Serial Number")
blade_slot=$(dmidecode | grep "Location In")
wwn_ports=/tmp/wwn.txt
port_name=$(cat /sys/class/fc_host/host[0-9]/port_name)
# store wwn ports
echo "$port_name" > $wwn_ports
# output
echo "Server Alias:" $fqdn_alias > $fqdn_alias.decom
echo "" > $fqdn_alias.decom
echo "WWN" > $fqdn_alias.decom
sed 's/\(..\)/\1:/g;s/:$//' $wwn_ports > $fqdn_lias.decom
echo "" > $fqdn_alias.decom
echo "$blade_slot" > $fqdn_alias.decom
echo "$blade_sn" > $fqdn_alias.decom
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you use `>`, it truncates the file before writing to it. So if you do this many times in a row, you're repeatedly emptying the file.

The best solution is to only open the file for writing **once**.

One option would be to group your commands using a block, like this:

```
{    
    echo "Server Alias: $fqdn_alias"
    echo ""
    echo "WWN"
    sed 's/\(..\)/\1:/g;s/:$//' "$wwn_ports"
    echo ""
    echo "$blade_slot"
    echo "$blade_sn"    
} > "$fqdn_alias.decom"
```

Using this approach, the file is only opened for writing once. As a bonus, I've added some healthy quotes around your variables, which is always a good idea.

Alternatively, you could go with a heredoc:

```
cat <<EOF >"$fqdn_alias.decom"
Server Alias: $fqdn_alias

WWW
$(sed 's/\(..\)/\1:/g;s/:$//' "$wwn_ports")

$blade_slot
$blade_sn
EOF
```

The lines up to `EOF` are redirected to the file. This option is nicer in my opinion, as it avoids so many calls to `echo` and allows you to use newlines. A command substitution is used to add the output of the sed command.

Answer (score 1):

Everytime you redirect with `>` it will overwrite the existing file. If you want to append to the file use `>>` so your lines should be, say

```
sed 's/\(..\)/\1:/g;s/:$//' $wwn_ports >> $fqdn_lias.decom
```

Or you could do them all in a block/subshell if you don't worry about the overhead and redirect the output from that like

```
( echo "Server Alias:" $fqdn_alias 
echo ""
echo "WWN" 
sed 's/\(..\)/\1:/g;s/:$//' $wwn_ports
echo "" 
echo "$blade_slot" 
echo "$blade_sn" ) > $fqdn_alias.decom
```

Comment: I do want to over-write the file. Just in case I want to over-write the script

Comment: @pirulo sure, make the first one `>` to start the file fresh each script, but right now yoiu're overwriting it with every line, so either make the rest `>>` to append to the new file, or write the whole thing in a block with a single `>`

Comment: It's better to use a group `{...}` (like in Tom Fenech's answer) rather than a subshell.